# Sending data from Laravel Controller to Routes & View

Tags: php, laravel

I am already sending a variable using Auth::login($user) and setting it inside an array in my routes. Want to send an additional array, everything i tried failed.

Code I have

**Controller**

```
public function callback(){
        if( !$this->fb->generateSessionFromRedirect() ){
            return Redirect::to('/')->with('message', "Error logging into facebook");
        }

        $user_fb = $this->fb->getGraph();

        if(empty($user_fb)) {
            return Redirect::to('/')->with('message', "User Not Found");
        }

        $user = User::whereUidFb($user_fb->getProperty('id'))->first();

        if(empty($user)){
            $user = new User;
            $user->name = $user_fb->getProperty('name');
            $user->uid_fb = $user_fb->getProperty('id');

            $user->save();
        }

        $user->access_token_fb = $this->fb->getToken();
        $user->save();

        $user_pages = $this->fb->getPages();
        // var_dump($user_pages);

        Auth::login($user);

        return Redirect::to('/')->with(array('pages' => $user_pages));

    }
```

**ROUTE**

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    $user = array();
    if(Auth::check()) {
        $user = Auth::user();
    }
    return View::make('hello', array('user' => $user));
});
```

So I want to send $user_pages, right now I have access to only $user. Tried running a foreach loop for $pages in my view, but doesnt identify the variable. So i am guessing I have to do something in routes and send it the same way I am sending $data.

Any Help?

Comment: Why on earth would you call a user `$data`? You make things more confusing for yourself and others if you come up with arbitrary variable names.

Comment: I don't see the controller method `callback()` being called in your code. In the declared route you're only returning the *data* variable (which I would rename to *user*). I'd recommend you to watch the Laravel beginner video's on Laracast.

Comment: have changed the variable name to user. and the callback is working fine, I just haven't posted the entire code, only the relevant code for this problem. on how to send the $user_pages to my view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `with` method flash data to the session so to retrieve it you need to use `session('key')`;

**Controller:**

```
public function callback(){
    //.......
    return Redirect::to('/')->with('pages', $user_pages);
    //.......
}
```

**Then:**

```
Route::get('/', function() {
    //From session
    $user_pages = Session::get('pages'); //session('pages'); for laravel >= 5.0
    $data = array();
    if(Auth::check()) {
        $data = Auth::user();
    }
    return View::make('hello', array('data' => $data));
});
```

Comment: What version of laravel are you using ?

Comment: `Session::get('pages');` may work instead of `session('pages');`.

Comment: @Press exactly ! he uses version 4.2 ;)

Comment: using laravel 4.2 & Session::get('pages'); did work. Thank you